# Group and sum from different tables

Tags: mysql, view

Let's suppose we have three tables

**T1**

```
 ID |Type| Class | Points
 111|1   |a101   | 12
 111|1   |b104   | 10
 112|2   |a112   | 40
 118|1   |a245   | 30
 186|2   |c582   | 23
```

**T2(Data for Type = 1 only)**

```
 ID |Type|EPoints
 111|1   |4
 118|1   |3
```

**T3(Data for Type = 2 only)**

```
 ID |Type|EPoints
 112|2   |9
 186|2   |15
```

And we want to have a View which will show ID,Type,sum(Points)+Epoints
for example

```
 ID |Type| Points
 111|1   | 26
 112|2   | 49
 118|1   | 33
 186|2   | 38
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I wish it was man, I wish it was...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select dt.id
     , dt.type
     , dt.points + coalesce(t2.epoints, t3.epoints) as points
  from (select t1.id
             , t1.type
             , sum(t1.points) as points
          from t1
        group
            by t1.id) as dt
left outer
  join t2
    on t2.type = dt.type
left outer
  join t3
    on t3.type = dt.type
```

Comment: total aside -- what are you using to format your SQL like that?  by hand?

Comment: ya, i do it by hand, unfortunately. i'd love to have something do it automatically but i don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might work (the join may need to be a LEFT one -- with a COALESCE around Epoints to transform nulls into zeros -- if you need to take precautions about records in `t1` without any matching record in either of the other tables, of course).

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Type, SUM(t1.Points) + other.Epoints
FROM t1
JOIN (
  t2
  UNION
  t3
) other ON (other.Type = t1.Type)
GROUP BY t1.ID
```